# Search for specific word list in a list of urls using Python

Tags: python, string, web-scraping

I'm trying to determine whether or not a list of URLs contain specific words. Below is my code:

```py
url_list = ['website1.com', 'website2.com']

cci_words = ['Risk Management', 'Labor', 'Migrant Workers']

total_words = []
for url in url_list:
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content.lower(), 'lxml')
    words = soup.find_all(text=lambda text: text and cci_words.lower() in text)
    count = len(words)
    cci_words = [ ele.strip() for ele in words ]
    for word in words:
        total_words.append(word.strip())

    print('\nUrl: {}\ncontains {} of word: {}'.format(url, count, cci_words))
    print(cci_words)

#print(total_words)
total_count = len(total_words)
```

But I keep getting this error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

Any ideas what should I do??

Comment: what is `url_list`? not sure if it's relevant here, tbh.

Comment: The problem is `cci_words.lower()`, `cci_words` is a **list**, there is no attribute 'lower'.

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop you cast cci_words to a list in the below line, so your program is throwing an error after it iterates through the loop a second time and tries to call lower() on cci_words.

```
cci_words = [ ele.strip() for ele in words ]
```

You seem to be making this probem quite complex where you could do something like this if you want any word in the list being present to return True.

```
def words_in_url_list(words: List[str], url_list: List[str]) -> bool:
    count = 0
    for word in words:
        word = word.lower()
        [count += 1 for url in url_list if word in url]
    return count > 0
```

If you want to check for all the words in the list, you could try this approach.

```
def all_words_in_url_list(words: List[str], url_list: List[str]) -> bool:
    comparison: set[str] = set()
    for word in words:
        word = word.lower()
        [comparison.add(word) for url in url_list if word in url]
    return len(words) == len(comparison)
```

Comment: Hi!! I'm trying now this approach that seems to work:   

link = ''

site = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
HTML = site.read().decode('utf-8')

for word in words:
    if word in HTML:
        print('\nUrl: {} contains word: {}'.format(url, word))
    else:
        print(word, 'not found')

My problem now is I can't use a list of links. :(